# Firefox extension, toolbar placement

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm brand new to Firefox extensions and am trying to update an old extension (that worked with Firefox 2.0) to have it work with 3.0. Everything seems to work, except the toolbar appears below the statusbar (which it does not in 2.0). It seems like the placement of it has to do with this statement (the "insertafter"):

```
<toolbar id="solvent-scrapeToolbar" 
  hidden="true" 
  flex="0.2"
  fullscreentoolbar="true"
  insertafter="FindToolbar">
```

How can I get it to display correctly?

Comment: I also tried insertbefore="status-bar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insertbefore="browser-bottombox" works